# Does PHP run time affects complex php scripts?

Tags: php, sql, runtime

Hello i'm currently maintaining a small website and a complex web application for a small Multi Level Marketing (MLM) company, and i noticed something odd while reviewing the database for a backup, i have checked the code and tested it out there's no issues because the condition won't allow for an empty value however there are 3 registered accounts that contains empty value basically a table that handles the matching of user accounts. Reviewed the database out of thousand user accounts there are only 3 user accounts that has empty values on some fields on the table.

My concern is that since this doesn't happen every time and since i've already checked the source code, does php runtime affects the complex script being executed? if not any thoughts about this kind of issues? are there ways to stop and cancel the process if an empty value was inserted in a table? Thanks in advance guys.

***UPDATE***
btw there are error handling implemented for this type of thing, however this odd occurrences still happened.

Comment: What do you mean "Does PHP runtime affect complex scripts". Do scripts magically change and do things different than how you coded? No. It's forseeable that an outside script modified that value, or perhaps those 3 values were stored before you made certain changes to your codebase that would have prevented these values from storing. Furthermore: It could be something entirely different, perhaps someone modifying HTML on the front end to exclude fields, or something you missed.

Comment: As far as "stop and cancel the process"? This seems weird, and odd. Why not just figure out what *could* be causing the empty values in the DB, and correct that? As far as cancelling a process? It should be the code that does that (ie. `if (empty($value)) exit;`)

Comment: yeah that's what thought however i did try to create a dev branch for this to test out and check however after registering 100 dummy accounts there's no issues all seems well.

Comment: this is weird because the script won't allow users to input any empty value because if they did the script won't execute and ask them to try again.

Comment: Is there a created date on these odd row, or some date? Maybe these were just stuff that didnt get cleaned out from some testing before the code was bullet proof

Comment: yes there are dates on the row however before they've made put the system live, all tables from that database is empty, doesn't contain anything. we've already checked it and there are no dummy accounts that's left after the web app went live.

Comment: You should consider auditing, and having someone else look at the code. Give you potential reasons why something can be empty: Sometimes it's something even *you* can miss.

Comment: my colleagues reviewed the code but they say everything's fine. as of now we're all wondering about it and decided to put an error handler to avoid pairing an account with empty fields. but seriously the cause of the problem is still unsolved.